# Angular and soap/WSDL through PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, soap, wsdl

I have build my application in cordova/angularjs, and for that i've been using http interceptors and php fils in factories modules to handle data.

Now i have to access 3rd party info info from another site with a soap client.

I have the following php for the service part (works here http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/getffbadsample.php):

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $clientSOAP = new SoapClient('http://ws.ffbad.com/FFBAD-WS.wsdl');
    $Auth["Login"]="xxxxx";
    $Auth["Password"]="xxxxx;
    $AuthJson = json_encode($Auth);
    $Query["Function"]="ws_getresultbylicence";

    $Query["Param"]["Licence"]="xxxxx";
ts)
    $QueryJson = json_encode($Query);
    //Appel de la fonction distante
    $Return = $clientSOAP->getResult($QueryJson,$AuthJson);
    print_r(json_decode($Return));
?>
```

in my js, i call in a function like this :

```
function loadwsffbad(){
    var players={}
    // $http.get("php/readPoona.php").success(function(data)
    // var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
    var urlphp="http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/";

            $http.get(urlphp+"getffbadsample.php").then(function(data)
            {
                players = data.data;
                console.log(players);
                // var recherche = "Philipe IHUEL";

                },function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                }
            );
```

When i debug it, i have data:null and status:0 as return.

i'm messing around with soap related posts, can you tell me if my approach can works in some way, or should i rewrite dedicated functions.
Regards.

Comment: Typo `$Auth["Password"]="xxxxx";`